# How to add a select for a year in react-dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, react-dates

It's a pain to swipe months right until I get to the right year with `react-dates`, is it possible to **add some select for the year/month**?

Comment: In case someone is unsure: Yes [self-answering is appreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since version **react-dates@17.0.0**! ([relevant pull request](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/pull/1106)).

1. `npm install react-dates@latest`
2. You will likely need to update a
   few things as per the [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates), because of the breaking changes
   (for me it was css mostly).
3. Then utilize the newly introduced
   `renderMonthElement` prop to write your custom month&year selectors,
   for example:

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import moment from 'moment';
   import { SingleDatePicker } from 'react-dates';

   class Main extends React.Component {
     state = {
       date: moment(),
       focused: true
     }

     renderMonthElement = ({ month, onMonthSelect, onYearSelect }) =>
       <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
         <div>
           <select
             value={month.month()}
             onChange={(e) => onMonthSelect(month, e.target.value)}
           >
             {moment.months().map((label, value) => (
               <option value={value}>{label}</option>
             ))}
           </select>
         </div>
         <div>
           <select value={month.year()} onChange={(e) => onYearSelect(month, e.target.value)}>
             <option value={moment().year() - 1}>Last year</option>
             <option value={moment().year()}>{moment().year()}</option>
             <option value={moment().year() + 1}>Next year</option>
           </select>
         </div>
       </div>

     render = () =>
       <SingleDatePicker
         date={this.state.date}
         onDateChange={(date) => this.setState({ date })}

         focused={this.state.focused}
         onFocusChange={({ focused }) => this.setState({ focused })}

         renderMonthElement={this.renderMonthElement}
       />
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

To slightly tweak the @lakesare answer for those wanting to list out, say, the last 100 years for a birthday, here's a code snippet :

```
renderMonthElement = ({ month, onMonthSelect, onYearSelect }) => {
    let i
    let years = []
    for(i = moment().year(); i >= moment().year() - 100; i--) {
        years.push(<option value={i} key={`year-${i}`}>{i}</option>)
    }
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <div>
                <select value={month.month()} onChange={e => onMonthSelect(month, e.target.value)}>
                    {moment.months().map((label, value) => (
                        <option value={value} key={value}>{label}</option>
                    ))}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select value={month.year()} onChange={e => onYearSelect(month, e.target.value)}>
                    {years}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

render() {
    return (
        <SingleDatePicker
            ...
            renderMonthElement={this.renderMonthElement}
        />
    )
}
```

Modify the for loop on line 4 to print out whatever years you need.

Comment: to make it more robust one can add ````i >= Math.max(0, moment().year() - numberOfYearsBack)```` in line 4.